What are the main views on the question of the relation between logic and human cognition?
Logicians tends to stick to formal logic, but there are presumably philosophers and probably psychologists specialised in the question of the role of logic in human cognition.
So what are the main views among academics on the question of the relation between logic and human cognition?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

Is asking for views different from asking for opinions, for purposes of this site?

It's asking for prevailing academic opinions rather than our opinions. I think that's legitimate.

Formal logic could be said to be a subset of the rational component of human cognition...

Two articles in the SEP may provide a good starting point and quick overview:

Informal Logic. Overview of "logic" in the broadest sense of the word, with focus on "real life", informal arguing. Lots of references
Argument and Argumentation. An "overview of the literature on argumentation drawing primarily on philosophical sources, but also engaging extensively with relevant sources from other disciplines", such as cognitive science and psychology. Huge bibliography.

The book Mathematical Epistemology and Psychology (1966) explicitly focuses on the relation between logico-mathematical thought considered as "pure" thought and as empirical, psychological thought process. Written by E. W. Beth, an important Dutch mathematician, logician and philosopher, and  Jean Piaget, the psychologist, known for this influential theories of childhood cognitive development. Beth gives an overview of the philosophical and mathematical history, including a chapter about logicism, and a chapter about strict deduction and heuristic procedures. Piaget writes about the relation between logic and psychology and, for instance, discusses the relations between self-evidence, intuition, invention/discovery, and logical necessity. If I'd have to summarize the questions addressed in this book in just one question, I might say: "What does it mean to talk about logic as 'the laws of thought' (from the point of view of logic -- as science -- and that of psychology)?"

+1 Nice summary :)

Thx. I specifically wanted to bring this book to the attention of @Speakpigeon because in the past he (if I understood him correctly) often defended the thesis that Aristotelian logic is essentially self-evident and expresses sth like the laws of thought. This book really goes into that, from the angles of logic, psychology and epistemology.

Piaget is cool, I don't know about the rest. "Nothing new is learned until existing systems have failed to maintain equilibrium." Words to live by. Some people would just say, "you have to hit bottom." Spare the rod and spoil the child, I guess. Very logical...

How human beings reason, draw inferences and update their beliefs has been studied extensively by cognitive psychologists for many decades. After all that work, there is no consensus among researchers on the subject. This suggests that different people reason in different ways, so it may be futile to expect a one size fits all account of human reasoning.
A traditional view asssumes that humans reason in the way that formal logics work, i.e. symbolically with formal rules. There are comparatively few psychologists willing to defend this today.
A popular position among cognitive psychologists is described and defended by Oaksford and Chater (1). Their studies suggest that many people engage in something like Bayesian updating. They have beliefs with a particular degree of strength and they increase or decrease those degrees based on information they acquire. Humans are poor at probabilistic reasoning, so this process only works very approximately.
Philip Johnson-Laird wrote many books on cognition and logic (for example, (2)). He considers that people reason by constructing mental models and searching for counterexamples. The process is fundamentally semantic rather than syntactic.
Some psychologists believe there is a specific kind of mental logic behind human reasoning. Gabbay and Woods (3) proposed a program to study this and attempt to formalise it.
A popular view of logic in the context of decision-making is that of bounded rationality. People tend to reach conclusions about what to do based on a need to find a satisfactory solution quickly rather than a best or fully correct solution. This is called satisficing.
Research has shown that humans are not particularly good at reasoning and are subject to many kinds of cognitive bias. Often when people reason it is an exercise in post hoc rationalisation.
There is much ongoing work in the area and plenty of disagreement. Some recent papers are listed below (4-7).

M. Oaksford and N. Chater, Bayesian rationality: The probabilistic approach to human reasoning, Oxford University Press (2007).

Philip Johnson-Laird and Ruth Byrne, Deduction, Essays in Cognitive Psychology, Erlbaum (1991).

Dov Gabbay and John Woods, "The New Logic", Logic Journal of the IGPL, Vol. 9, No. 2, pp. 141-174 (2001).

Alistair Isaac and Jakub Szymanik, Logic in Cognitive Science: Bridging the Gap between Symbolic and Connectionist Paradigms, Journal of the Indian Council of Philosophical Research (2):279-309 (2010).

Jacek Malinowski and Rafał Palczewski, Logic in cognitive science, Logic and Logical Philosophy 20 (1-2):3-5 (2011).

Paweł Balcerak, Role of Logic in Cognitive Science, Studia Humana 7 (1):21-30 (2018).

Jan Woleński, Logic in the Light of Cognitive Science, Studies in Logic, Grammar and Rhetoric 48 (1):87-101 (2016).



And because people are always comparing minds to programs (shouldn't that be the other way around?) it is important to say that neurons and brains overall are fundamentally analog, not digital. Like turning a knob, not flipping switches. They are vague, non-repeatable and not really predictable, not even very reliable actually except that piling trillions of neurons together tends to yield some consistency. The whole thing never evolved to do logic or math at all, avoids those as much as possible and does them badly. So even asking about logic is like asking about how bears ride bicycles.

According to Dov Gabbay, his "New Logic" is an effort to accommodate logical fallacies to modern formal logic. Looking at them as, somehow, legitimate reasoning.

@ScottRowe "neurons and brains overall are fundamentally analog, not digital." True, but computers are themselves fundamentally analogue, if anything really is.

@ScottRowe - Bears ride bicylces very well - in the circus. Is philosophy the circus?

@mudskipper you mean, compared to engineering?

@ScottRowe - I don't quite know anymore what I meant :)

You may want to look at the work of cognitive psychologists Daniel Kahneman and Amos Tversky.
The term cognitive bias might be relevant.

I've been wanting to look at Tversky's work. Do you have more specific recommendations about which of his studies are relevant for logic and for the question  how logical reasoning develops?

You might enjoy van Benthem's (2008) writing on this. He offers examples of how cognition and social practices influence the development of logics, citing, e.g., Prior's work on temporal structures and Lewis and Stalnaker on comparative orderings of possible worlds. He concedes that much of the work in this direction is informal:

Logicians analyzing natural language, or computer scientists modeling ‘common sense’, tend to go by their own intuitions, anecdotal evidence from colleagues, email surveys of sometimes surprising naiveness, and other easy procedures that avoid the laboratories and statistical packages of the world of careful experimental design. But even so, experimental evidence is relevant, in that these theories can be, and sometimes are, modified under pressure of evidence from actual usage, even when it comes through these home-grown sources.

He also points to work in the other direction, where cognitive scientists take non-classical logics and use them to model social and cognitive phenomena. An example is Stenning and van Lambalgen's (2005) analysis of the "suppression task" in psychology using nonmonotonic logic. Probability theory may be viewed as a kind of logic and it is used in cognitive science too; try e.g., Pfeifer (2013) and references that follow.
One key element of cognitive science studies that use logics is how people interpret tasks, and often have different interpretations, which can be modelled as choosing a logic and setting its parameters. Geis and Zwicky (1971) observe that logic students sometimes map the natural language indicative "if A, then B" to a biconditional in logic, so even in formal logic class interpretations aren't naive.
Cognitive scientists don't expect non-specialists to be aware of the logics that model their interpretations and inferences, e.g., here's Da Silva Neves, Bonnefon, and Raufaste, E. (2002):

... even if we expect human inference to corroborate these properties, we know
of no sufficient reason to think that lay reasoners would recognize any rationality postulate as valid, neither that they would conscientiously use them to guide their reasoning. [...W]e assume that human inference is constrained by
knowledge organisation in memory and that its formal properties emerge from
a spreading activation process operating directly on knowledge structures.

References
van Benthem, J. (2008). Logic and reasoning: Do the facts matter? Studia logica, 88, 67-84.
Da Silva Neves, R., Bonnefon, J. F., & Raufaste, E. (2002). An empirical test of patterns for nonmonotonic inference. Annals of Mathematics and Artificial Intelligence, 34, 107-130.
Geis, M. L., & Zwicky, A. M. (1971). On invited inferences. Linguistic inquiry, 2(4), 561-566.
Pfeifer, N. (2013). The new psychology of reasoning: A mental probability logical perspective. Thinking & Reasoning, 19(3-4), 329-345.
Stenning, K., & van Lambalgen, M. (2005). Semantic interpretation as computation in nonmonotonic logic: The real meaning of the suppression task. Cognitive Science, 29(6), 919-960.
